# Syncing OneNote 2010 notebook with Sharepoint 2010 creates a folder on sharepoint but no notebook (0xE000076C error)

Tags: sync, sharepoint, microsoft-onenote

I'm trying to sync a OneNote notebook with my Sharepoint site.

I create a new notebook, choose to store it on the network and give the location of a document library I have created on Sharepoint, but it won't sync.

The error message I get is...

> OneNote cannot sync this notebook. An error occurred while communicating with the Web Server where the notebook is stored. (Error code: 0xE000076C)

When I create the notebook it creates a folder on Sharepoint in the location where I chose to create it, but it doesn't create any files within that folder.

I am able to upload documents into the Sharepoint document library, so am fairly sure the permissions are ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new document library with OneNote as the default doc template on your SharePoint Site first, then you can sync your notebooks.  When browsing to your new SP library within OneNote, type the URL for your SP site into the address bar and then navigate to the new doc library.

Answer (score 1):

Just started using OneNote and had a similar issue.  I had to go to Versioning settings for my document library and turn off the options for requiring a document to be checked out before edit and setting it to "No Versioning".

Comment: Where do you do that? I cannot find anything similar in OneNote...